# jQuery Dynamic Selector with Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html div ids dynamically generated.

```
<div id="1-test" class="new">    
<div id="2-test" class="new">
<div id="3-test" class="new">
<div id="4-test" class="new">
```

I need to show/hide these divs on a click.  I'm trying this

```
var filterid='test';
    $('.new[id$=filterid]').each(function (index) {
        $(this).toggle();
    });
```

But, it is not going inside loop.  Can anyone advise the mistake here?  Thanks in advance.

If I do this, I see the loop running.

```
$('.new').each(function (index) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

When I filter based on id dynamically and try to enter, the loop doesn't work!!

Comment: Search for "string concatenation". `$('.new[id$=' + filterid + ']')`

Comment: Once you remedy the concatenation issue Vohuman mentioned, you can then drop the each as it's not needed. `$('.new[id$=' + filterid + ']').toggle();`. An dyou shouldn't even need the `.new`.

Comment: j08691 and Vohuman, thanks for the quick reply.  You are absolutely right!! I tried string concatenation earlier but it didn't work. But, I tried again now, and it works :) strange though!!

Comment: However, I get a different issue, the div hides initially and shows up automatically after a couple of seconds. Not sure what the issue is!!

Comment: Nothing in code shown would cause hidden elements to suddenly appear

Comment: my stupidity again!! I didn't keep "return false" at the end of the click event where I called this method resulting in invoking post back in asp.net!! All is well now, thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mark solution...

```
$('.new[id$=' + filterid + ']').toggle();
```

Thanks to Vohuman and j08691

Answer (score 0):

Please check my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nc3BJA9mjBOc9wUWIrBR) and see if this gives you the functionality you were after. I believe it should from what you had described.

Instead of:

```
var filterid='test';
  $('.new[id$=filterid]').each(function (index) {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

I have added a "click" event in the form of:

```
$(".new").click(function(){
    var filter = $("#filter").val();
    if ($(this).attr("id") != filter) return;
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

This checks if the id of the filter is the same as that which was clicked and only allows them to be toggled.

If you require a refinement to the filtering let me know.
Good luck!